# Почему не появляются отзывы?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Решил сделать отзывы на сайте. Использовал для создания модуля отзывов вот этот источник `https://it-black.ru/sozdanie-stranicy-oprosa-kachestva-predostavljaemyh-uslug-na-php/`

Создал как в примере таблицу (вот моя таблица)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в корень папки создал файл db.php
Вот его содержимое (* - заменил пароль)

```
<?php 
$dblocation = '*******'; // имя хоста
$database = '*******'; // имя базы данных 
$dbuser = '*******'; // имя пользователя
$dbpasswd = '************'; // пароль пользователя

// устанавливаем соединение с базой данных 

$link = mysqli_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $database) or die("Не могу подключиться");  
mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die ('Не могу выбрать БД');

//установка кодировки
$link->set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

Далее создал файл формы form.php

```
<?php include_once 'db.php'; ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Отзывы о продукте</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

 <?php $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `Otzivy2` ORDER BY id DESC") ?> 
 <?php while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

<div class="reviews">
  
<div class="review_text">
<b>Имя:</b> <?= $res['name'] ?> | <b>Дата:</b> <?= date("d.m.y | <b>Время:</b> H.i", strtotime($res['date'])) ?> | <b>Оценка:</b> <?= $res['rating'] ?>/5
<hr>
<br>
<?= $res['message'] ?> <br>
</div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<div class="content">
<h2>Отзыв о продукте</h2>
<h3>Все поля обязательны для заполнения</h3>
<br>
<div class="send"> 
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="review">   
<h3>Оцените продукт</h3>
<div class="rating">
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
<input type="date" name="date" hidden="true">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Оставить отзыв">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Затем в файл index.php добавил вот этот код

```
<?
include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

// преобразуем специальные символы в текст

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$rating = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rating']);

// заносим данные из формы в переменные и проверяем на ошибки

$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message']));
$rating = strip_tags(trim($_POST['rating']));
$date = $_POST['date'];

// заносим дату и время отзыва
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

// проверка введенных данных

if($name != '' AND $email != '' AND $message != ''){ if (!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $email)) {$err = 'Неверно введен е-mail.';}

// отправка данных в бд

mysqli_query($link, " INSERT INTO otzivi (name, email, message, date, rating) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$date', '$rating')");

// закрываем сеанс 

mysqli_close($link);

//редирект

header ("location: index.php");
   }
}

include_once 'form.php';
?>
```

С базой соединение происходит. При заполнении формы данные записываюся в базу. Но. На странице index.php отзывы не появляются, то-бишь обратно с базы данные почему-то не приходят. Вопрос Почему? Где-то ошибка?

Сайт на голом php+html
В базу значения попадают, а на странице отзывы не появляются, то-бишь обратно не забираются данные

Comment: не страшно такой ужас к себе на сайт добавлять? Это же прямой доступ к базе данных - заходи кто хочешь, бери что хочешь.

Comment: @Ипатьев Исправил

Comment: Я извиняюсь, *что* исправил? Это параметры никому сто лет в обед не нужны, можно было оставить. Я про сам код говорю.

Comment: Это код с открытого источника интернета. Других я не нашел

Comment: @Ипатьев Если у вас есть лучший, работающий пример, поделитесь, буду очень благодарен, С уважением!. P/S Сайт без CMS

Comment: Знаешь такую сказку, там сестрица алёнушка говорила братцу иванушке, "не пей из открытого источника, козлёночком станешь"? Не нужно по всяким левым сайтам побираться. Надо или учиться программировать нормально самому, или поставить какую-нибудь готовую приблуду типа disqus

Comment: @Ипатьев Без сторонних фрэйморков и плагинов

Comment: Все назвния файлов вымышленные, что там можно взломать на сайте без CMS?

Comment: @Ипатьев Я и пытаюсь учится и мне не понятно почему отзывы не появдяются на странице, безопасность это другой вопрос

Comment: @Arcadiy, если Вы спрашиваете в общем, то самое ценное это информация из базы данных. Для работы с бд лучше использовать PDO, но я так понимаю Вы только начали изучение и поэтому пока не нужно

Comment: @Ипатьев да, только начал

Comment: @Arcadiy, нужно дебажить каждый шаг и смотреть что происходит, так вы лучше поймете и сможете найти ошибку

Comment: @r.mcreal Я здесь написал, когда уже все пересмотрел по 10 раз, так и не понял

Comment: var_dump($result) что выдает?

Comment: мне кажется или тут разные таблицы использованы для записи и чтения?  INSERT INTO otzivi и SELECT * FROM `Otzivy2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исходя из представленного кода видно, что чтение ведется из одной таблицы `SELECT * FROM` Otzivy2 `ORDER BY id DESC` а запись в другую `INSERT INTO otzivi (name, email, message, date, rating) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$date', '$rating')` соответственно без дополнительных действий нет шанса получить сохраненные данные. в источнике, ссылка на который приведена в вопросе указано SELECT * FROM `otzivi`

Comment: Спасибо большое